# Centos 7 auditing pipe-user-pages-soft being exceeded

Tags: linux-kernel, auditd

The following patch introduced behaviour where a user has the default buffer size of new pipes changed if the total amount of memory used by pipes exceeds a threshold.

https://lkml.org/lkml/2016/1/18/171

Is there a way to use auditd to trigger on this limit being exceeded.

Thx

Comment: Good question! **pipe-user-pages-soft** and **pipe-user-pages-hard** can be disabled by setting them to 0.